# Grafana requests per second explanation

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm struggling to understand how to create simple Graphana dashboard that will calculate requests per second. I found several topic about that but still I'm confused how this works.

For testing purposes, I did 4 quick requests, then another 2 and then 1 more.

And I have a query like this
`increase(request_time_count{status="200"}[1m])`

The result looks like this
[image]

Then, I change query to look like this
`increase(request_time_count{status="200"}[5m])`

And result changes to
[image]

And that's where I'm getting confused, how should I understand that? How should I choose correct range vector? Should it be `1m` or `5m`? From what I see, `1m` is a bit more accurate? It basically says:

Each sample in last minute had increase of X (comparing to what?). 
Now if I would select `5m`, it says - each sample in last 5 minutes had increase of X.

So I'm getting much more samples in longer time period and they are compared against samples further in the past? Please explain it to me in Layman's terms

Answer (score 2):

Prometheus calculates the given `increase(request_time_count{status="200"}[5m])` query **independently per each point** displayed on the graph. Now let's look at how does Prometheus calculate the `increase(request_time_count{status="200"}[5m])` query at the point with timestamp `08:04` on the graph above:

1. It selects time series matching the `request_time_count{status="200"}` [series selector](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#filtering) on the time range `(08:04-5m .. 08:04]`, e.g. on the time range `(07:59 .. 08:04]`. Note that the `07:59:00.000` timestamp isn't included in the time range, while the `07:59:00.0001` is included in the time range.
2. It fetches **raw samples** stored in the database for the selected time series on the `(07:59 .. 08:04]` time range.
3. Per each selected time series it calculates the increase for the fetched **raw sample values**. Basically it subtracts the first raw sample value from the last sample value per each time series, since [counters](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#counter) increase over time. The calculations may become slightly complicated if counters are reset to zero on the selected time range.
4. It returns the resulting `increase()` individually per each selected time series.

Basically, `increase(m[d])` at timestamp `t` returns counter increase on the time range `(t-d .. t]` individually per each time series matching `m`.

See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html) in order to better understand key concepts used in Prometheus ecosystem.